# Should I return the callback or just run it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently writing a couple of functions which work async.just imagine this example

```
signUpUser(userInfo, callback) //callback(err, token)
createToken(userInfo, callback) // callback(err, token)
```

now I'm wondering whether to return the callbacks or just call'em inside my functions, I mean for example in the `createToken`:

```
createToken(userInfo, callback) {
   var token = ...;
   callback(err, token); //or
   return callback(err, token);
}
```

cause as long as the callback belongs to another programer and if for what ever reason he decides to return something in his code this simply blocks it.

**EDIT**:After I posted my question I got the answer that it's not possible to return anything but as I went deeper in my codes and also node js I found the opposite.the code below runs well!!

```
function foo(a, callback) {
    console.log(a);
    return callback(a);
}

function bar(a) {
    return a;
}

console.log(foo(3, bar));
```

Comment: yeah that code isn't asynchronous, so the "callbacks" aren't callbacks.

Comment: *"I'm currently writing a couple of functions which work async"* Your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39204742/revisions) shows functions that **do not** "work async." Due respect, but we can only answer based on the information provided. If you tell us they're async when they aren't, it's no great surprise that the answers don't address your situation.

Comment: @KevinB: Callbacks don't have to be asynchronous. See `Array#sort`, `Array#forEach`, etc. (I don't see any point at all to the callbacks in the edit, though.)

Answer (score 3):

You've said your functions are asynchronous. That means they **can't** return the result of calling the callbacks, because they return before the callbacks are ever called. So they should return nothing or some useful context value, but not the result of calling the callback. So of the two choices in your question:

```
function createToken(userInfo, callback) {
    startAsyncProcess(function() {
        // It's done, may have failed (err), may have succeeded (token)
        callback(err, token);
    });
}
```

---

Separately and a bit off-topic: Look at using promises rather than manual callback mechanisms (unless of course the manual style is to fit into a large established codebase). E.g.:

```
function createToken(userInfo) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        startAsyncProcess(function() {
            if (/*...it succeeded...*/) {
                resolve(token);
            } else /* ...it failed... */ {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

(Of course, if `startAsyncProcess` provides a promise, you'd use that promise.)

Usage:

```
createToken(/*...info...*/)
    .then(function(token) {
        // It worked, use the token
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // It failed
    });
```

Comment: well thanks but as in the edit I found the opposite!

Answer (score 1):

If you returned the callback, so how you will now that the execution of the async class finished?

That's why we send the callback to the asyc work, to call it after finishing its functionality or getting the response from the server.

You can use **Promises**, and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) the MDN documentation.

The idea behind the promise, it you return an object that has methods for each case of your async action like **fulfilled**, and **rejected**